# With spring boot vaadin spring.jpa.open-in-view not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin8

I have a Spring Boot based app with vaadin frontend, but the `spring.jpa.open-in-view` function is not working.
The spring boot version is 2.1.2.RELEASE.
As I see the `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` is registered correctly, but it is called once, when the application loaded.
When any backend call invoked it is not triggered.